# Differentiate the modulus function.

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How do I differentiate $ f(x)= 1+|x-2| $ ? How to deal with modulus sign here?

Comment: It is not differentiable at the point $x=2$. At all other points it is. To differentiate it, write down the function for $x<2$ and $x>2$ separately. Also, draw a picture!

Comment: How did you find that it is not derivable at x=2? I also need to learn that.

Comment: Yes, you should learn that.

Comment: I'm asking you to help me.

Comment: I understand, but I am not a math teacher.

Comment: That's fine but how did you do it yourself? There has to be some conditions for it.

Comment: This notation is usually the absolute value function. $|x| = \cases{-x , x<0\\x , x\geq 0}$

Comment: If you [plot the graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D1%2B%7Cx%E2%88%922%7C) then you can see the sharp point at $x=2$. We can't find a derivative here as there is no gradient, as we can see about half way down [this page](http://www.hyper-ad.com/tutoring/math/calculus/derivatives.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>1$, $f(x)=1+(x-2)=x-1$ and $f'(x)=1$

If $x<1$, $f(x)=1-(x-2)=3-x$ and $f'(x)=-1$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{[(2+h)-1]-1}{h}=1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{[3-(2+h)]-1}{h}=-1$.

Therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$ does not exist. $f$ is not differentiable at $x=2$.